# How to run fsck manually?

Tags: initramfs, fsck

After I switch on my computer, I have a prompt called (initramfs), the message on the screen asks to run the command "fsck" manually.

Answer (score 2):

In the (initramfs) prompt I type the line:
"fsck /dev/sda2 -y", then the computer starts to compile the command-line successfully in order to check the file system with error before to work correctly.